# How To Make My Portable Hard Disk / USB Drive Undeletable and Uneditable?

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a portable (external) hard disk and I use it on many different computers/laptops.

I want to know if it is possible to make the files and folders in my hard disk undeletable. So no matter who uses it, they should not be able to delete, edit, rename, or apply any other modification to the file/folder except me. However, they should be able to read/view it.

Also, if I set some kind of security, others should not be able to change its settings.

Please let me know if there's any security I can use to protect my hard disk.

Comment: This would be done in the group policy editor, gpedit. Unfortunately Home edition or lower does not have gpedit, but can be added>>>>https://www.itechtics.com/easily-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-10-home-edition/

Comment: Another method>>>>>>https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/prevent-file-deletion-and-file-renaming-in-windows/

Comment: Why not use a DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Though... If you want to be able to connect it to any computer (without taking additional measures on the computer)...

The basics:

- You need write protection build into the external case (a switch which most solutions have won't suffice since everyone would be able to disable that).
- In addition the drive has to be encrypted and the encryption has to be coupled to the external case as well so if the drive is removed from the external casing the data won't be readable.

You'll have to find an affordable device that can handle both requirements (so far I've only seen write protection on external cases with an unprotected on/off switch).

A second (less secure) solution would be to put a external drive with a unprotected HW on/off switch in a second enclosure which you can lock.

PS. you can do it [in the file system directly](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-write-protect-an-external-hard-drive/cf7ed39c-d949-4f42-a5be-ea7200890201) so it's independent from the machine the HD is connected to but but this can be easily undone.